# c++ passing const value by reference

Tags: c++, stl, constants

I have such method in the class.

```
 Word Sentence::parse_word(std::string &word) {
 }
```

Everything works fine. 
After some considerations I've come to conclusion that it's not good. 
Because inside of this  method, `std::string word` isn't changed. 

So it'd be better to pass it as `const std::string &word` to make usage of the method more obvious and clear.

Moreover having the method with such signature I make impossible calling it like `parse_word(string("some_text))` -

So I have decided to change signature to:

```
Word Sentence::parse_word( const string &word) {
    string::iterator iter1= word.begin();
    iter1=find( word.begin(),word.end(),'/');
      /*some other code */
  }
```

I.e. I don't change that string inside this method.
I understand that I use here methods like find that accepts non-contant value, but it'd be better to pass string as const!

and as it's suspected it can't be compiled because of it:
[image]

I wonder, is it at all good what I try to do? 
 And how is it possible to cast const string to string? (I tried using C-style casting or const_cast - without success).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use a `const_iterator` instead of `iterator`, since you are invoking `begin()` through a reference to `const`:

```
string::const_iterator iter1 = word.begin();
//      ^^^^^^
```

In agreement with the interface of standard containers, [`std::string` defines two overloads of the `begin()` member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/begin): a non-`const` qualified one that returns a `std::string::iterator`, and a `const`-qualified one that returns a `const_iterator`.

Since you are invoking `begin()` through a reference to `const`, the latter overload returning a `const_iterator` is picked (the non-`const` one is obviously not viable).

This is why the compiler will refuse to compile the above example. In C++11 you could have avoided this kind of troubles by using `auto`:

```
auto iter1 = word.begin();
```

Answer (score 4):

If you pass a `const string` or reference to `const string`, you need to use a `const_iterator`:

```
string::const_iterator iter1= word.begin();
```